# Need to preview a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

My problem is I just want to preview a Lightning component in the developer console.  There are a ton of ways to make lightning components in all sorts of other mediums, but I just want to click preview and see it.  I believe I need to have a "dummy" lightning app to host it.  An outline of what I have now is for the Component called "testApp.cmp"

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
////code
<h1>hello world, please display this</h1>
</aura:component>
```

and the Lightning App called "testApp.app":

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
   <aura:dependency resource="c.testApp"/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Question is little vague. Do you want to preview a component without the need for the application? Or are you unable to preview even with the application?

Comment: @Avinash, I really just want the easiest way to display the lightning component.  So I just want to see the "hello world" without having to add it to a tab or page

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Having a dummy app for the purpose of previewing is typically what I do. You don't need Lightning Out for this, though. Just put the component directly in the app:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
  <c:helloWorld />
</aura:application>
```